# How can I upgrade Python 2.7.6 to Python 2.7.7 on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I upgrade Python 2.7.6 to Python 2.7.7 on Windows? Should I install new version in a separate directory, change all appropriate environment variables and install all required third-party modules again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short yes, however it's a little bit complicated to change every time the environment variables and may be some incompatibilities. I recommend you to use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) which allows you to run different versions of python with different modules.
Actually `virtualenv` is the best way to proceed... 
Here i provide link on how to install virtualenv on windows
[virtualenv on windows](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can install Python 2.7.7 on top of Python 2.7.6 . Just be careful to specify exactly the same installation directory you used for 2.7.6 .

Comment: When I do that and run $python --version. it still shows 2.7.6 and not the updated one that I just installed. What could be the reason?